# C# PropertyGrid - making all properties not bold

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

In a PropertyGrid form element, when I add properties to my categories, some appear in Bold.
Now, I know that it suggests that they are the default values in that category. My question is how to make all properties *not* bold?
I know one possible way is changing the DefaultValueAttribute attribute, but I was wondering if it can be done in a different way: [this post](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=97571) suggests that I might have to use reflections, which is kind of mystical for me at the moment :)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each property, you can add:

```
private bool ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}() { return false; }
```

Other than that, you are into the realm of custom `PropertyDescriptor` implementations via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`.

Note that this pattern is used in a number of places, but in some (`XmlSerializer`, for example), it is required to be a `public` method.

Comment: what about the suggestion in message #9 in that forum?
http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showpost.php?p=460034&postcount=9
it seems to be more general

Comment: @bks that is the "custom `PropertyDescriptor`" route I mentioned above; sure, you *can* do that, but it isn't trivial - not least, you'd need to write a daisy-chained `PropertyDescriptor` first.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Default] Attribute on your own properties, otherwise you can do -at your very own risk- the following horrible hack.

Tried in .Net Framework 4.7.2. You'll loose the bold on categories aswell.

```
class MyNoBoldPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid
{
    private void SetFontNoBold()
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            object lv = Controls[2];
            Type lvType = lv.GetType();
            FieldInfo pi = lvType.GetField("fontBold", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (pi != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(lv, Font);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        SetFontNoBold();
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
    }           

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x210) // WM_PARENTNOTIFY
            SetFontNoBold();        
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```